# Runtime error while creating integrations in WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am Creating an integration using data mapper Mediator. I encountered the error given below.

```
ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:StagingIntegration} Runtime error occurred while mediating the message java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputReader.readFromInputStream(JSONInputReader.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputReader.read(JSONInputReader.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputBuilder.buildInputModel(InputBuilder.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler.doMap(MappingHandler.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:438)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:314)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:322)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aren't you sending a payload with the request?

Comment: @ycr I am sending the payload in the request body